# Proving $ \sqrt{n} = a + \frac{-n + a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a high school student, I do math advanced and extention, I was told to prove the equation:

$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{-n + a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}
$$

My teacher originally gave me the equation as:

$$\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{n + a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}$$

He made the "$n$" a negative because apparently you cant get an answer without it, but I have been unable to get an answer from the updated equation, could someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax. Did I transcribe your question properly? It seems like you probably want $$\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{n - a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}$$ since that's what makes the equation true, but I don't think that's what you originally wrote.

Comment: Something that might help you: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$.

Comment: The general idea would be to factor the numerator into a product containing $(a+\sqrt{n})$ so that the fraction is eliminated.

Comment: "extention"? or, "extension"?

Comment: The first equality has at most one solution, the second equality has no solution unless $a=0,$ while @HallaSurvivor's suggestion is indeed an identity (as $a$ and $x$ vary).

Answer (score 1):

If we want to prove the relation (for $a\neq -\sqrt{n}$) we need to show that (note that this is the equation from @HallaSurvivor)
$$\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{n-a^2}{a+\sqrt{n}}$$
Bringing the $a$ to the other side gives
$$\sqrt{n}-a = \frac{n-a^2}{a+\sqrt{n}}$$
Multiplying by $a+\sqrt{n}$ then gives
$$(\sqrt{n}-a)(\sqrt{n}+a) = n-a^2$$
And working out the product on the left-hand side (like in the comment of @PC1) indeed gives the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{-n + a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}
$$

We can factor a<sup>2</sup> - n as ($\sqrt{n}$ + a)($-\sqrt{n}$ + a)

$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{(\sqrt{n} + a)(-\sqrt{n} + a)}{a + \sqrt{n}}
$$

The expression ($\sqrt{n}$ + a) cancels out in the numerator and denominator, and we are left with

$$
\sqrt{n} = a + (-\sqrt{n} + a)
$$

Which translates to

$$
\sqrt{n} = 2a - \sqrt{n}
$$

If we transpose the $\sqrt{n}$ to the other side
$$
2\sqrt{n} = 2a
$$
$$
\sqrt{n} = a
$$

This identity is not true for all values, so the initial equation is also not true for all values - There might be special values that make it true (namely, it is only true if $\sqrt{n}$ = a), but you are right in saying that it cannot be proved right for all values

On the other hand, the modified equation that @HallaSurvivor suggested is an identity, and it can be solved for all values (except a = $-\sqrt{n}$)

$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{n - a^2}{a + \sqrt{n}}
$$
$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \frac{(\sqrt{n} + a)(\sqrt{n}-a)}{a + \sqrt{n}}
$$
$$
\sqrt{n} = a + (\sqrt{n} - a)
$$
$$
\sqrt{n} = a + \sqrt{n} - a = \sqrt{n}
$$